# Cascading DropDownList: Updating an existing value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following JS which I use to populate a dropdownlist (`District`) depending on which `Department` the user chose.

Here the code:

**First** I populate the Department dropdownlist and I insert a 'Select' value to use it as default:

```
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        List<Department> DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
        DepartmentList = (from department in _context.Departments
                          select department).ToList();
        DepartmentList.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0, DepartmentName = "Select" });
        ViewBag.ListofDepartment = DepartmentList;
        //...etc
    }
```

**Then** I pass it to the View, which is a PartialView called _Create

```
<form asp-action="Create" role="form">

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">District</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here, I'm setting the District dropdownlist as a Empty list, since I'll populate it with JS.

**After that** I include the following Js to Populate the District dropdownlist, first with a Select, and then with the values required depending on which Department was chose.

```
<script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
            $('#DistrictID').html(items);
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
            var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
            $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#DistrictID").empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                    items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works **fine** when I create a new Store.

**The problem**:

When I want to update an existing Store, I can put the Department value inside the dropdownlist, but the District dropdownlist don't populate with the value which that Store has or the other possible values in case the user wants to update this particular Store district.

[image: Screenshot]

**IDEA:** I suspect that I must change the 2nd part of the JavaScript to:

- Add a conditional if I'm seeing a **new** or an **existing** store.
- If it is new, do what you are doing now,

  - Else, instead of 'Select', put the corresponding District (and show this) and fill the dropdown with the rest of districts corresponding with that Department.
- After this point, if the user change the Department dropdown, do what you have been doing up until now.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Additional info**

I'm using a ViewModel since I need the properties from several models: Department, District and Store:

```
public class StoreIndexData
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public int DistrictID { get; set; }
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }

    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public int StoreChainID { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string StoreAddress { get; set; }
    public int StoreArea { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Get Method to get the info of the Store that is been edited:

```
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        List<Department> DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
        DepartmentList = (from department in _context.Departments
                          select department).ToList();
        DepartmentList.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0, DepartmentName = "Select" });
        ViewBag.ListofDepartment = DepartmentList;

        //Lista de Cadena
        List<StoreChain> ChainList = _context.StoreChains.ToList();
        ChainList.Insert(0, new StoreChain { StoreChainID = 0, ChainName = "Select" });

        ViewBag.ChainList = new SelectList(ChainList, "StoreChainID", "ChainName");

        StoreIndexData edit = new StoreIndexData();
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            var store = new Store();
            store = _context.Set<Store>().Include(d=>d.Districts).SingleOrDefault(c => c.StoreID == id.Value);

            StoreIndexData model = new StoreIndexData()
            {
                StoreID = store.StoreID,
                StoreChainID = store.StoreChainID,
                StoreName = store.StoreName,
                StoreAddress = store.StoreAddress,
                DistrictID = store.DistrictID,
                DepartmentID = store.Districts.DepartmentID,
            };
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Stores/_Create.cshtml", model);
        }

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Stores/_Create.cshtml");
    }
```

Finally, this is the Json I use in the second JScript to grab the list of Districts once the Department has been choose in the creation of a new store:

```
public JsonResult GetDistrict(int DepartmentID)
    {
        List<District> DistrictList = new List<District>();
        DistrictList = (from district in _context.Districts
                        where district.DepartmentID == DepartmentID
                        select district).ToList();
        DistrictList.Insert(0, new District { DistrictID = 0, DistrictName = "Select" });
        return Json(new SelectList(DistrictList, "DistrictID", "DistrictName"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode, you could just populate select with `ViewBag.ListofDistrict` similar to `ViewBag.ListofDepartment`.

```
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    List<Department> DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
    DepartmentList = (from department in _context.Departments
        select department).ToList();
    DepartmentList.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0, DepartmentName = "Select" });
    ViewBag.ListofDepartment = DepartmentList;
    ViewBag.ListofDistrict = string.Empty; // Render blank
    //...etc
}

public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    List<Department> DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
    DepartmentList = (from department in _context.Departments
        select department).ToList();
    DepartmentList.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0, DepartmentName = "Select" });
    ViewBag.ListofDepartment = DepartmentList;

    // Get district list for given department Id
    ViewBag.ListofDistrict = DistrictList;
    //...etc
}

<select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))">
</select>
```

Comment: Hello, this helped me to get this done, but an update on the JScript was also needed to identify if I was in an update or new store scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Another option is sent in a Json.

In your Controller:

1. Get the list of districts for departments:

   ```
   List<SelectListItem> DistrictList = GeneralService.Mt_DistrictList_x_DepartmentID (DepartmentID );
   ```
2. Send it in Json format:

   ```
   return Json(new { data = salida, DistrictList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   ```

In your jQuery code:

3. Clean the dropdown:

   ```
   $("#ddlMotivo").empty();
   ```
4. Fill the dropdown with DistrictList items  (in AJAX success:  section):

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.DistrictList.length; i++) 
   {
     $("#ddlMotivo").append("<option value='" + data.DistrictList[i].Value + "'>" + 
     data.DistrictList[i].Text + "</option>");
   }
   ```